# Get web api appSettings as collection of name-value pairs

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to retrieve the values inside the 'appSettings' section of my web.config file as a collection of name-value pairs? I want to create an api controller method that returns this object so that I can access the collection of settings from my front-end(as a JSON object ideally). I tried returning `WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings` but it only returns an array of string containing only the name of the settings (without the value). I had been searching for an answer for almost 2 hours but couldn't find one. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple mechanism provided for this that I am aware of, for the reason that the [NameValueCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) type is more than a simple Name/Value dictionary and might not always be easily represented as one.

Each key in a **NameValueCollection** *may* have *more than one value*.

When more than one value is assigned to a particular **Name** then the *Value* of that *Name* becomes a comma separated list of all of those values.  If any one of those values itself contains a comma then this can make deciphering such values difficult (i.e. application/context specific).

As a result, you have to decide how you need to handle the contents of a specific **NameValueCollection** in each case.

If your particular **AppSettings** consist of truly simple name/value pairs or you are happy to deal with any comma separated multi-values then you can of course do something similar to:

```
var dict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, String>();
var settings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

foreach ( var k in settings.AllKeys )
{
    dict.Add(k, settings[k]);
}

var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

Hopefully that will set you down the right track if not provide a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually thought of this solution but thought there would be another solution that does not require looping through the items. But it seems like there's no easier way to do it than this solution. I appreciate the additional info about NameValueCollection. If no else comes up with a better solution within 2 hours, I'd accept your answer as the correct answer :) Thanks a lot!